# Activating iOS Developer mode on 15.6.1

Tags: iphone, ios, settings

I'm trying to activate Developer mode on my `iOS 15.6.1` device. All references I find ([example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device)) say to open `Settings > Privacy & Security`. Well, that doesn't exist, only `Settings > Privacy`. Opening `Privacy` and scrolling to the bottom of the list, there's supposed to be a `Developer Mode` toggle. That, too, does not exist.

How do I activate Developer mode for this version of iOS? Where is that toggle located?

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device Quoting from that page "Developer Mode, introduced in iOS 16 and watchOS 9..."

Comment: The simplest way is to connect your iPhone to a Mac running xCode.

Comment: @PtitXav I forgot to mention that the device is connected to my Mac and the app is launched through Xcode. Shaking the device does not trigger the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as "Developer Mode" on 15.6.1 - so you do not need to enable it. This is only possible to do on iOS 16 and onwards.

Comment: Ok. Then something else is going on. I am unable to access the Developer menu by shaking the device even though the device is connected to my Mac and the app is launched through Xcode. Shaking it does nothing.

Comment: Shaking the device is not something that generally brings up a developer menu. Why do you think this would be? (i.e. please refer to where you have read about this). Perhaps you're specifically referring to a React Native (or for example Expo) development setup - but you seem to be leaving a lot of important information out.

Comment: This is a React Native app. I started with the assumption that the developer menu was on the device when actually, it's probably served up by the localhost dev server. Apparently, my assumption is flawed. I'll check react-native forums.

Comment: You should have mentioned React Native. The developer menu is actually on the device and not on the localhost dev server… however it is not a feature that Apple provides or something that exists in iOS. It is a feature implemented in React Native that exists when you run their development app. I.e. you need to compile the app you’re running on the phone with that developer menu, otherwise it won’t work. If you find this difficult, I will recommend using Expo, as this makes it easy to get everything setup on the device.

Comment: I know. Sometimes, we are so close to the details that we forget that others have no context. I am quite familiar with how RN works, but have had little need to launch the dev menu from a device until now. I do appreciate your input.

Comment: It usually works without problems as long as you have built the app for Debug. I have never had any problems getting it to work. Note that if you choose the Release target in Xcode, the development menu won’t be there at all of course.

Comment: I understand. My colleague has no problems either. No idea what the issue may be.

Comment: Download the Expo app and check with that. Either you have compiled the your app incorrectly, or the sensor is broken in the phone. If Expo works, you know which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue on ios 15.7. The answer was nonsensically buried in iPhone settings. Once you've got your phone wired up to Xcode as a simulator, attempt to build and you'll get the message about "Developer Mode". Close that then go to *Settings > General > VPN & Device Management*. There's a panel there to "trust" the specified developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you install an app via Xcode onto an iPadOS 15/iOS 15 device, an entry for developer mode will show up in the settings app, right above the list of all of your installed apps.

It's not called "Developer mode" per se, but in reality it's the same thing of which Developer mode was made out of since iPadOS 16/iOS 16.